# Restrict Microsoft OAuth sign in to only specific applications

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Oauth for single sing on for our web application. At the moment, if a user logs in using Microsoft credentials, it also signs them into their Office to 365, Outlook etc...

Is it possible to limit the scope of a OAuth login to only login to certain applications? In this instance, only log in to our application and not log in to other applications such as Office 365, Outlook etc...?

Comment: Did you not use client id?

Comment: Yes, the client_id is required for OAuth to work, however to the best of my knowledge, it doesn't limit the scope of any login just to that client id.